# Total Variation on compact interval

Tags: limits, exponential-function, bounded-variation

Let $f(x)=e^{-x} \cos x$. Show that $f$ is of bounded variation on any compact interval. For each $k$ in $\mathbb{N}$, compute $V(f ; 0,2 k \pi)$ and show that $\{ V(f; 0, 2 k \pi): k$ in $\mathbb{N} \}$ is an increasing sequence that is bounded above. Find its limit.

Since the exponential function is an increasing function, and $cos x$ has a bounded derivative, both of them will be bounded variations on any compact interval, along with their additions and multiplications. However, computing precisely the supremum of $\Delta f(x_j)$ summations for any partition of $[0; 2 \pi k]$ seems a little bit vague. Are there any hidden tricks to evaluate the total variation on $[0; 2 \pi k]$? Proving monotonicity and boundedness would be simple afterward

Comment: If $f \in C^{1}$ then the total variation of $f$ on $[a,b]$ is $\int_a^{b}|f'(t)|dt$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you derive without using the integral definition? The original meaning of total variation relies on the summations of delta differences, and there should be some method to evaluate the supremum of this expression!

Comment: Can anyone suggest further ideas regarding the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that total variation is additive in the sense that $V(f;a,c)+V(f;c,b) = V(f;a,b) $ and it follows that
$$V(f; 0, 2k\pi) = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1} V(f; 2j\pi, 2j\pi + 2\pi) $$

For $x \in [2j\pi, 2j\pi + 2\pi]$ we have  $f(x) =  f(2j\pi +u) = e^{-2j\pi}e^{-u} \cos (2j\pi +u) =e^{-2j\pi}g(u)$ where $g(u) = e^{-u} \cos u$ for $u \in [0,2\pi]$.

Hence,
$ V(f; 2j\pi, 2j\pi + 2\pi)= e^{-2j\pi}V(g,0,2\pi)$ and

$$V(f; 0, 2k\pi) = \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{-2j\pi} V(g; 0,  2\pi) = V(g; 0,  2\pi)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}e^{-2j\pi}  =  V(g; 0,  2\pi)\frac{1- e^{-2k\pi}}{1- e^{-2\pi}}$$

Thus, $\{V(f;0,2k\pi)\}_k$  is an increasing sequence with $V(f; 0, 2k\pi) \nearrow V(g;0,2\pi)/(1 - e^{-2\pi})$ as $k \to \infty$.

It is easy to compute $V(g;0,2\pi)$ since $g$ is monotonic on the intervals $\left[0,\frac{3\pi}{4}\right] $,$\left[\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}\right] $ and $\left[\frac{7\pi}{4},2\pi\right] $.

Comment: Awesome! Have not seen such a brilliant solution for a long time!

Comment: @Snowflake: You're welcome.